# Preparation of cycloalkanes

Tags: hydrocarbons

Is it possible to get cyclooctane from calcium suberate? Is this reaction similar to one when getting cyclohexane from calcium adipitate?

[image]

Comment: Consider to substantiate your question by provision of details what reaction(s) you have in mind to create cyclohexane/cyclooctane.  Don't hesitate to include a reaction scheme (e.g. with the help of ChemDraw's [sample page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html)) to prepare an illustration. For one, it documents you invested some effort to solve the question by your own. For two, it improves the quality of your question for future readers potentially interested in this method.

Comment: Synthesis is done in opposite direction. Why would anyone synthesise cyclohexane?

Answer (score 1):

#### Kolbe's Electrolysis

It is a decarboxylation dimerization reaction that follows a free-radical pathway and, formally, occurs by passing current through an alcoholic $\ce{KOH}$ solution to ensure presence of carboxylate ion instead of carboxylic acid. In your case, the base is $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$.

| Intermolecular | Intramolecular |
| --- | --- |
| [image: intermolecular kolbe's electrolysis reaction] | [image: intramolecular kolbe's electrolysis reaction] |